# Display "editable" PDF form

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, pdf

Working on ASP.NET db with SQL Server db. My client has several PDF forms. He wants me to transfer them to webpages so that the users can (1) load a pdf form filled with data from a database or (2) edit the forms directly and click a button to save it to the db.

For each "pdf webpage", I was thinking of converting the target pdf file to a jpeg then using that as the background image of the page. Then overlaying textboxes, checkboxes, etc... in the appropriate places. Then programming against the .net controls as usual. Do you have any better idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Overlaying everything would be difficult. Just design forms that match the structure of the PDF and take the form data and insert it to the PDF upon submission.

Comment: Extending on the above comment, you certainly do not want overlay on all platforms. If you have mobile users they will hate pan and zoom all over.

Answer (score 0):

Make the fillable forms available for download (showing in the web browser gets more and more tedious because the Acrobat browser plug-in architecture is less and less supported, and the browser's PDF viewing components are too dumb to deal with fillable forms).

Provide a Submit button on the form which submits the data back to the server. If you use the Submit method HTML POST, you can use the same server-side scripts as if it were a web form.

This means no fiddling with overlays etc.

And BTW, never, ever, ever use JPEG for non-photographical graphics.

Comment: Interesting suggestion. Why do you say that last statement? Curious.

Comment: About that last statement: The short answer is "Artefacts". The way the compression works in JPEG creates very bad artefacts around high contrasts. If you have a b/w image (such as black text on white background), you only have high contrasts, and you should be able to see the artefacts. Looks horrible and highly unprofessional…